# How do you do a simple popup window in Telerik?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

How do you do a simple popup window in Telerik?

What would be the code-behig C# code in aspx:

===========

```
 <telerik:RadWindow ID="modalPopup" runat="server" Width="360px" Height="360px">

           <ContentTemplate>

                <div style="padding: 10px; text-align: center;">

                     <telerik:RadButton ID="rbToggleModality" Text="Toggle modality" OnClientClicked="togglePopupModality"

                          AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" Height="65px" />

                </div>

                <p style="text-align: center;">

                     The format of the dates are incorrect.  Please use two digit month and

                     a four digit year for proper formatting.

                </p>

           </ContentTemplate>

  </telerik:RadWindow>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/modalpopup/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
        var composeScreenWindowName = "composeScreen";
        var communicationTypeId = 'CT01';
        var url = $page.url.create("You page url that you want to display");
        var win = $window.createPopup(url, { size: "800,600", behaviors: Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Close | Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Maximize | Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Move | Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Resize, name: composeScreenWindowName });
```

try telerik popup using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try it ,

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" Text="open the window" runat="server"    
OnClientClick="openWinContentTemplate(); return false;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
                function openWinContentTemplate() {
                    $find("modalPopup").show();
                }
</script>
```